# When trying to add Spring JAR files in STS (Spring Tool Suite), I'm encountering an error that says 'Class file editor source code not found

Tags: spring, jar, spring-tool-suite

When trying to add Spring JAR files in STS (Spring Tool Suite), I'm encountering an error that says 'Class file editor source code not found.' How can I resolve this issue?"

when i am adding spring jar files after trying to access ApplicationContext i am getting class file editor source code not found unable to find the ApplicationContext.class

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: sir i created java project in java project i added a spring context and core jar files and downloaded jar files in maven repository i am not able find applicationcontext it says class file editor source not found attach source folder

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using Maven or Gradle to build your Spring application, but instead configure the classpath of your project in the IDE manually, you need to download the source JARs for those libraries manually and attach them as source JAR to the classpath entries in your project configuration in the IDE. But I would strongly argue against doing that and instead use something define your dependencies using Maven or Gradle. The IDE integration for those build tools downloads the sources automatically for you.